# Rails form flipping days and months

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that received dates via two variable :start and :end. When I input the date they look right, but when I save, the model receive a date with the days and months flipped, and when the day is greater than 12, say 13th of March, it will simply show nil error. 
My form field look like:

```
<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker4" data-target-input="nearest">
      <%= f.text_field(:start, value: f.object.start ? f.object.start.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %p') : nil, class: "form-control datetimepicker-input", data: {target: "#datetimepicker4"}, placeholder: "#{t :From}", required: true) %>
      <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker4" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
        <div class="input-group-text"><span class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Same for `:end` variable

The input form looks like :
[image: Form picture with right dates]

The results looks like:

[image: Saved result with incorrect date]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you try to use US date format, but rails is parsing submitted params with month and day switched. I am not sure if you would prefer to use US or international date format and I advise you to check how rails is handling parsing submitted params.

Also, have a look at defaults of calendar date time picker you use.

UPDATE.
I will try to provide more details. In one of my projects I am using a similar date time picker that looks like this

[image: datetime picker]

When submitted you will have the following params in our controller 
`{"date_time_picker_input_field"=>"2020-01-20"}`. 
The reason my date time picker formats date as YYYY-MM-DD is that in the view code I am using an option that is taken by datetimepicker code upon initialisation, something similar to

`date_format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',`

(this can be different in the date time picker you use and I suggested earlier to check documentation on options you can use).

I don't have to use strftime on date time provided to `text_field`, because date time JS code will format the date in format of your choice.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Any chance you would  know which component i should change ? I have been stuck on this for 3 days :(

Comment: i can see the params being passed as: "start"=>"02/21/2020 3:01 PM", "end"=>"02/21/2020 4:02 PM"

Comment: Your params are like that because you formatted them with the code `f.object.start.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %p')`, see what you will get when flip day and month positions like this: `f.object.start.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %l:%M %p')z`